# building a realistic scenario using real traffic data and SUMO

Tags: dataset, openstreetmap, sumo

I would like to build a real scenario using real road network and real traffic data. This is for testing purposes of some research work.

I know how to extract a map form OSM according to the tutorial on SUMO website. I have 2 questions:

1- from where can I extract real traffic data that corresponds to extracted map? data like avg. speed of roads? number of vehicles on each road, vehicle density, etc.

2- how can I use that data to generate routes to be used in the scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no general open data source for traffic demand data. It is possible to generate something from population statistics using SUMO's activitygen or from traffic counts using the dfrouter or the flowrouter. There are also tools available for importing origin-destination-matrices but most of these sources you have to get from the city or region in question.